# If query equals certain value then subquery to find another value

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables - Invoices, Invc_tender, and Invc_fee

Here is my current query

```
 SELECT so.so_no, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.cust_id, i.invc_no, i.created_date, it.amt, i.invc_type, it.tender_type, it.crd_type, ife.fee_type
      FROM rpro.invoice i
      LEFT JOIN rpro.so so ON so.so_sid = i.so_sid
      LEFT JOIN rpro.invc_tender it ON it.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
      LEFT JOIN rpro.invc_fee ife ON ife.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
      LEFT JOIN rpro.customer c ON c.cust_sid = i.cust_sid
      WHERE i.invc_type IN (0,2) AND ife.fee_type != -2 AND i.created_date >= '2014-12-10' AND i.store_no = 0
```

What I would like to do is if ii.tender_type is equal to 7 then perform the following query to find and pass the actual values to the initial query results for it.tender_type, it.crd_type, and it.amt

```
 SELECT it.tender_type, it.crd_type, it.amt
      FROM rpro.so so
      LEFT JOIN rpro.invoice i ON i.so_sid = so.so_sid
      LEFT JOIN rpro.invc_tender it ON it.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
      LEFT JOIN rpro.invc_fee ife ON ife.invc_sid = i.invc_sid
      WHERE ife.fee_type = -2 AND so.so_sid = (The SO_SID of the current invoice result)
      ORDER BY i.created_date desc
```

In regards to the one tables relationships.  The SO table has a one-to-many relationship with Invoice, and Invoice has a one-to-many relationship with both Invc_tender and Invc_fee.  Essentially if the ii.tender_type = 7 instead of looking at the current invoice find the other invoice attached to this SO which has an ife.fee_type = -2

Was this possible with one query or nested queries? Or was this something I would have to perform multiple queries?

Comment: 1. Change WHERE to AND

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query returning the SO_SIDs you need